# Remote Desktop Solution for Ubuntu 14.04 host and a Windows Thin Client w USB support?

Tags: 14.04, usb, sound, remote-desktop

**THE GEAR:**

- Midtower running Ubuntu 14.04 for the host
- An HP t610 Thin Client running a stripped-down embedded copy of  Windows 7 and VMWare. Note that the client factory resets with every boot.
- DAC is a Behringer U-Control UCA202 which outputs the host's audio via USB on the client to my hi-fi.

**CURRENTLY USING:**

I tried NoMachine but it has a few key problems:

NoMachine fails to detect any display devices half the time I connect, so I'm stuck with 320 x 240 default resolution.

It [lacks support for client USB devices when connecting to Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.nomachine.com/TR11L04682). As I use a USB DAC for this music workstation it rules the service out as an option.

**SO FAR I'VE EXPLORED:**

NoMachine - (see above)

TightVNC - miserable performance; best for remote viewing only with no input devices

RealVNC - sluggish refresh rate at all quality settings. No USB sound support

VMWare - not avail. for Windows

Vinagre - not avail. for Windows

Remmina - not avail. for Windows

KRDC - not avail. for Windows

Are there any viable solutions to pair an Ubuntu host with a Windows 7 client with remote USB support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fiance kindly reminded me that the simplest and most direct solution is often the best.  I disconnected the thin client and brought the Ubuntu tower back into my music studio.  YES - It is horrifically loud (the catalyst for this entire project), but I was stunned by the improved image clarity on my desktop.  Furthermore, eliminating the client instantly restored the function of my DAC and my connection speed increased from 25Mbps to 57.96Mbps with this one simple change.

It appears the best course of action in my particular scenario is to eliminate thin clients from the formula. Instead, I can drill a hole in the floor for the cables and set the tower up in the room below the studio where it can make all the noise it wants without interfering with my work.

At worst I'll have to buy a few cable extensions - pennies compared to what I'll get back once I sell off the client.

Thank you, dear.  Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

The only remote server/client I didn't see in your list is x2go.

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/x2go-server-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: I think it's a good answer, it gives him another remote desktop option to try

Comment: OP thinks it's a good answer as well.  I would try it but I've decided on an alternative course of action.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Thanks @innerspaceboy - Glad you found a solution that worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

NoMachine here. Make sure you are using version 5.0.47.

Essentially there are two problems being described.

1) USB redirection not working in user's set up. We've checked this and can't reproduce it. The problem described was fixed a while back, so you should check that you are using the latest version. Still, it would be interesting to know the exact version that you have installed on the server and clients sides. Additionally, tell us:

- are the local and remote devices visible on the device list during forwarding?
- is the device connected (green dot in NoMachine menu) and can you see it in the USB list on Ubuntu (lsusb command from console)?

2) A display problem. To help us investigate further, we need to know if it’s headless setup (see here for more info: https://www.nomachine.com/AR10K00710). If it is, does it have a graphics card installed? And what the model is, if so?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I've already factory reset the client, removed all software and the ethernet powerline from my network.

It was a headless setup, with a Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS780.  I see from the link you kindly provided that there are additional steps required for a headless setup, so the error was mine.

I was using v5.0.47 when the problems occurred.

While the USB device did show up in the NoMachine menu, it did not on the Linux PC unless I plugged it directly into a USB port on the tower, itself.

Thanks again.  For my scenario, running extended cables will be sufficient for my needs.